# Opencart 2.1, автозаполнение неработает, ошибки в js

Tags: javascript, opencart

Opencart 2.1.0.1 (пробовала и другие версии, 2.2.0.0, русские), не работает все поля, где необходимо автозаполнение (подгрузка категорий, товаров, клиентов)
(пробовала в двух браузерах - хром и фокс, локалка и сервер).
Выдает ошибку:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'source' of undefined 
>   (common.js)

Ругается где-то на эти строки:

```
this.timer = setTimeout(function(object) {
object.source($(object).val(), $.proxy(object.response, object));
}, 200, this);
```

потом

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'hide' of undefined

там же в `common.js`

Их решить не удалось, помогите разобраться, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 0):

проблема решилась, программа антиспам
(антиреклама) блокировала работу сайта.